# C# Task Pane Repaint in Excel when Excel's ScreenUpdating = False

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I am using a c# add-in to complete some complex calculations. I have a custom task pane in which I am using to show the progress (new lines are appended to a textbox).

This works great when Excel's ScreenUpdating = True but the task pane does not repaint until the process is complete when ScreenUpdating = False. Is there any way to force the task pane to repaint whilst Excel's ScreenUpdating = False?

Many thanks

Mark

Answer (score -1):

I have decided to use a Windows form instead which will still of course repaint when Excel's ScreenUpdating is set to False.

Kind regards

Mark